# Delayed QTimer start?

Tags: qt, qt4

Having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around Qtimer this morning.

Here's the basic idea:

I have a QTimer that is started by clicking a button.
Once it is active, every 5 minutes it calls a function (let's call it start() ).

Start() calls a seperate function (call it work() )using QtConcurrent. Thus, it returns quickly, even though processing is still occuring.

Here's my problem:
I want to call work() a number of times, once after the other. My issue is that currently, it will call the work() function multiple times before it has finished processing, which, since it interfaces to hardware, doesn't work.

How should I go about this properly?

EDIT:

Here is the basic flow of the program:

- User clicks startTimer().
- StartTime() calls timer->start()
- when the timer emits a signal, it calls Start()
- Start() does some light UI stuff, then makes does 
     future = QtConcurrent::run(...work()...) //work takes a long time
     watcher->setFuture(*future)
- somehow (this is my issue), when work() is done, I want to call it again (4 times, to be exact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question you want to avoid running the `work()` function in multiple threads simultaneously.

Use a [QMutexLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html) at the top of your `work()` function and add the corresponding [QMutex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmutex.html) to your class definition.

THis way the execution of the `work()` function will be blocked until the previous execution has finished.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds good. However, how should I check to see when the execution is finished (and then immediately call work() again)?

Comment: Once you have a mutexlocker at the beginning of your work function the mutex will be called as soon as the work() has finished. During execution all other threads will be blocked at the beginning of the work() function. Automatically as soon as the mutex is unlocked the first waiting thread will lock it and start execution. Check [Synchronizing Qt Thread for more details](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads-synchronizing.html)

Comment: ohh, so it is more of a "delayed execute" than "denied execute"

Comment: Yes, if you want to deny execute you could check if the mutex is locked `mutex.tryLock()` at the beginning, and if this returns false abandon the execution of the `work()`

Answer (score 0):

If your `work()` function had an anomaly where it took 20 minutes for some reason, would you want to then run the 4 next `work()` callbacks as soon as possible...or still want them to be spaced out by 5 minutes despite the delay?

If what you want is really 5 minute *intervals*, then you should use a single-shot timer that is re-queued each time you complete a work item.  This way, you don't have the potential of winding up with a big blocked up queue of QTimer messages that can flood in and run all at once:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop